# Extract multiple longest common prefix from a file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am a newbie in python and stuck in one problem to get the longest common prefix from a file. I have found the solution on the web to get the common prefix between 2 strings, but unable to get any solution from a file

Below program returns me 9, whereas the output I want is 9415007 and 95420070144.

```
fname = 'Book1 - Copy.csv'
fh = open(fname)
file2 = fh.read()

a = list(file2.split())
prefix_len = len(a[0])
count = 0
lst = list()

for x in a:
    prefix_len = min(prefix_len, len(x))

    while not x.startswith(a[0][: prefix_len]):
        prefix_len = prefix_len-1

prefix = a[0][: prefix_len]
print(prefix)
```

I expect the output to be 9415007 and 954200701441.

Sample data:

```
9415007301578
9415007301585
9415007014416
9542007014416
9542007014417
9542007014418
```

Comment: You ask for the longest common prefix, but there's no longest in your output. Something is wrong, output or task.

Comment: Hi Olvin,
If you see the sample data, the longest common prefix should be from the entire list.
9415007 is the longest common prefix from the first 3 strings, whereas 95420070144 is the longest from last 3 strings.

Comment: Do you want to extract all prefixes or only the logest one?

Comment: By  the way, longest prefix from last 3 lines is `954200701441`

Comment: Oh yeah. Just edited the post.:)
I want to extract only the longest one.

Comment: The answer is 9. If you have two different prefixes, they aren't common

Comment: The longest common prefix considering all 6 entries is 9, and that is what your code looks for at the moment. If you want to look for something else you need to rephrase what you are looking for.

Comment: "the output should be 9415007 and 95420070144." Why??

Comment: Yes, I am looking for 9415007 and 95420070144, as this is requested by our client. These codes correspond to some company id.
Company A: 9415007
Company B: 95420070144

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The os.path module contains a commonprefix function that you can use.  To find the longest prefix between any two lines, you should first sort the lines and then compare consecutive pairs (keep the longest).

For example:

```
from os.path import commonprefix
sLines  = sorted(lines)
longest = max((commonprefix([a,b]) for a,b in zip(sLines,sLines[1:])),key=len)
common  = commonprefix(lines)
print(common,longest) # 9, 954200701441
```

*note that your sample data only has "9" as the common prefix to all lines because there are instances of 94... and 95...  To get 9415007, you would need to remove the last 4 lines.*

If you need to do this on a company by company basis, you will need to group the data by company identifier (first 7 characters):

```
from collections import defaultdict
companies = next( d for d in [defaultdict(list)] if [d[s[:7]].append(s) for s in lines])
companies = {c:sorted(s) for c,s in companies.items()}
companies = {c:max((commonprefix([a,b]) for a,b in zip(s,s[1:])),key=len) for c,s in companies.items()}

print(companies) # {'9415007': '94150073015', '9542007': '954200701441'}
```

Comment: Hi Alain, Is it possible to still get 9415007, as it is company id? Company id cannot be less than 5 digits. Can we put a condition to get 9415007 too?
I cannot remove the lines from the source data but would like to extract the company ids from the list.

Comment: Thanks, Alain. This is awesome. This is what I was looking for.

Comment: Hi Alain,
The code is working fine when the company identifier is 7 digits, but it doesn't return the correct value when it is more than 7. Company identifier can vary from 7-10 digits. Any idea how to tackle that?

Comment: You have to know a pattern that will determine the length of the company number part and use that instead of `s[:7]` in the list comprehension.  It is is complex, I would suggest creating a function to extract the company number and use it there ( e.g. `getCompNum(s)`to replace `s[:7]`)

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure, that this is not the best solution, but definately simplest one.

```
data = """9415007301578
9415007301585
9415007014416
9542007014416
9542007014417
9542007014418""".splitlines()

longest_prefix = ""
for i in range(len(data) - 1):
    temp_prefix = ""
    for j in range(min(len(data[i]), len(data[i+1]))):
        if data[i][j] == data[i + 1][j]:
            temp_prefix += data[i][j]
        else:
            break
    if len(temp_prefix) > len(longest_prefix):
        longest_prefix = temp_prefix

print(longest_prefix)
```

Output:

```
954200701441
```

Comment: Thanks, Olvin for the code. The code returns output as 
9415007001829
9
954200701441, but I am looking for 9415007 and 954200701441.

Comment: @DeepeshMoad, are you kidding me? You,ve said in comments "I want to extract only the longest one."

Comment: Hi Olvin,
Apologies, I read it wrong. I want to extract all the prefixes, as mentioned in the question. Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: @DeepeshMoad, it's not all the prefixes. With your input prefixes will be `['94150073015', '954200701441']`